# Wildcard search with cypher query and spring neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

When I execute the below query in neo4j console, i get the correct result set.
start n=node:search('username:*') return n.username;

I am using spring data neo4j in my java web app.

In the repository code, i defined query as:

@Query("START n=node:search({0}) RETURN n.name as name, n.username as username
Parameter passed
{0} = 'username:*'

There is no exception but the result set size is 0.

Can you please help me resolve the issue?

Comment: Not sure, but try to refere to your parameter with a String instead of an Integer (0), e.g. {luceneQuery}

Comment: Are you sure the data is indexed correctly? Index-name `search` index-key `username` ? Can you check that with a plain lucene lookup?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the whole lucene query cannot be a parameter in Cypher, as far as I know. You'll need to resort to string concatenation/interpolation, probably. Similar to the issue I posted about relationship types as parameters: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/340

Comment: I was stuck with something else couldn't try this out for sometime. I am still not sure why the wild card search doesn't work when i use @Query annotation and give the query - @Query("START n=node:search('username:*') RETURN n.name as name, n.username as username. I could however run this in my app with Result<Map<String, Object>> result = neo4jTemplate.query(query, map). When i passed the same query in the argument, it worked. Thanks.